# How to click on the next page

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to click on the next page, the pages are in the form 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10. I don't know the end page.

The xpath for page 1 is `'//*[@id="gvSearchDentistlist"]/tbody/tr[52]/td/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/a'` and so on for page 2 and page 3. Now I have to click on the next page till end. How to click using xpath?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get(url)
driver.maximize_window()

soup = bs(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
table = soup.find('table',{'id':'gvSearchDentistlist'})

next_page = True
while next_page == True:
    soup = bs(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
    table = soup.find('table',{'id':'gvSearchDentistlist'})
    try:
        rows = table.find_all('tr')
        for row in rows:
            if len(row.find_all('td')) == 6:
                data = row.find_all('td')
                name = data[1].text.strip()
                print("NAME:"+name)
                root_url = data[5].input['onclick'].split(",")[4]
                link ='url1'+root_url
                print("LINK:"+link)
    except:
        pass
    time.sleep(5)
try:
     tr = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="gvSearchDentistlist"]/tbody/tr[52]/td/table/tbody/tr/td[1]').click()
except:
    print ('No more pages')
    next_page=False
driver.close()
```

Comment: please read [mcve] and edit your post accordingly, HTML code is missing for the page on which you performing operation, if possible provide url of site, add the error stack trace, data samples if any and elaborate what you are trying to do.

Comment: show me the website please, I can help

Comment: url = 'http://dciindia.gov.in/DentistsSearch.aspx?Reg_Type=D&RegUnder=0&IDRId=&IDRName=&CourseId=0&RegDate=0&CouncilId=' @Ahmed I. Elsayed

Comment: do you have any solution @Ahmed I. Elsayed

Comment: I have a solution to get the total number of pages if you want

Comment: then you can loop as many times as pages exist

Comment: yes please tell me how to get total number of pages? @Ahmed I. Elsayed

Comment: The page says **206085** records total and you have 50 records per page
so 206085 / 50 = 4121.7, so basically 4121.7 * 50 = 206085 this means that you have 4121 pages and the last page has 0.7 * 50 records which is 35.

Comment: Does this answer your question?